# Finding the Final Digits in a Stacked Exponents Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, totient-function, tetration

> How to find the the last two digits of the number  $$\underbrace{\huge
>  7^{7^{7^{...}}}}_{1+n}$$ When there are $n$ sevens in the ascending
>   exponents.

I have no idea how to condense this or where to begin.

Answer (score 2):

We are interested only in the last two digits, so we care about the remainder of your power tower, modulo $100$.

---

My hint is this: $$7^4 \equiv 2401 \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$$
$$7^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$$

Answer (score 1):

By Eulero-Fermat theorem, the [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) $\text{ }^n7$ verifies for all $n\ge 3$:
$$
\text{ }^n7\bmod{100} \equiv 7^{(\text{ }^{n-1}7 \bmod{\varphi(100)})} \equiv 7^{7^{(\text{ }^{n-2}7 \bmod{\varphi(\varphi(100))})}} \equiv \text{ }^37\bmod{100}.
$$

Indeed $\varphi(\varphi(100))=8$, and $\text{ }^{n-2}7 \bmod{8}=7\bmod{8}$. Notice that the same method, together with Chinese remainder theorem, works for the reduction of any congruence of the type $\text{ }^na\bmod{b}$.